# no matching key exchange method found when using SFTP

Tags: ssh, rhel, sftp, key-authentication

My remote server(A) is having RHEL 8 OS and another server(B) runs with RHEL 5. I need to SFTP to server A to B. I have used below method.

```
sftp usr@10.58.148.111
```

But I am getting below error.

```
Unable to negotiate with 10.58.148.111 port 22: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

Then I used as below,

```
 sftp -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 usr@10.58.148.111
```

Then I am getting different kind of error..

```
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to 10.58.148.111 port 22: error in libcrypto
Connection closed.  
Connection close
```

Here are my ssh -v output.

```
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes256-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes256-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 need=32 dh_need=32
debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 need=32 dh_need=32
 ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to 10.58.148.111 port 22: error in libcrypto
```